# Chaining methods JSONObject/JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, android

I am a bit new to Java. I recently tried to chain method calls together but the IDE continues to prompt errors. Here is a sample.

```
int motoYear = (int) modelYear.get("yearsRange").get(0);
```

*modelYear* is type JSONObject. The first .get() returns a JSONObject, and the second .get() returns a JSONArray and the final value is an int (if this was to work as intented).

The second .get() shows an error "Cannot resolve method 'get(int)'" in the IDE. Is there a slick what to typecast the expected returns of the individual .get() without assigning the values to variables one-by-one? Is something like this possible? I am currently using Android Studio IDE.

Comment: What is the return type of `get(String)` which you call on your `modelYear` object? Does that type have a visible `get(int)` method?

Comment: Goto windows -> preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist; Give .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ under Auto activation triggers. Then as you type
modelYear.get(" Bring cursor over get and tell us the return type. Same way for the other .get(. And make sure you have the .get s when the content assist comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29). The method `get()` of `JSONObject` returns a value of type `Object`. And Object doesn't have any `get()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `modelYear.yearsRange` is a `JSONArray` of `int`s, you want to do this:

```
int motoYear = modelYear.getJSONArray("yearsRange").getInt(0);
```